# Why I have to install packages in R 3.1.2 again when I restart my PC

Tags: r, installation, package

I have installed `dplyr` package successfully! But "YOU HAVE NOT THIS PACKAGE IN YOUR R" when I run `library(dplyr)` today. I haven't remove this package before, why?

Answer (score 1):

Packages can be found in different library paths, look in which directory they are: (It is common after an update to have a new directory path)

```
.libPaths()
```

In my case I have: 
[1] "C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.1" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"

Also you can look at your packages:

```
library()
```

It also good to update your packages once in a while.
If running under windows:

```
library(installr)
update.packages()
```

One trick I use to manage my packages, is to have a R.code dedicated to this purpose, which is open most of the time. Also I periodically backup my packages list, so I can re-install them quickly:

```
save_all_packages <- rownames(installed.packages()) 
write(save_all_packages, file="...list_all_packages.txt")
```

Hope this helps.